# What UI framework is http://mega.co.nz/ using?

Tags: javascript, frameworks, web

I am interesting in what framework http://mega.co.nz/ is using. Specifically instantaneous page/section transitions with urls like :/#/pagename and smooth transition effects. Also form input handling is slick.

Comment: How do you know they're using one at all?

Comment: requirejs, backbone, jquery-scrollpane and lodash

Comment: How do I know they are using one? I looked at the source code and it's all there. Super minimized however so it's hard to understand what they use.

Comment: Just maximize it with a javascriptbeautifier.

Comment: Nice. There is a js for that.. :).

Comment: Is still valid the question... but the answers???

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Backbone jQuery, loaded with requirejs and compiled in main.js with r.js. Instead of underscore.js it uses lodash.

There are also these jquery plugins used: 
jquery.easing, jquery.jscrollpane, jquery.mousewheel, jquery-validate, jquery-placeholder.

The scrolling feature is implemented using [jScrollPane](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html).

Comment: How are they encrypting data in browser?